# Fastest way to check if a given word exists in a fixed list of words

Tags: dictionary, rust

This may not be specific to Rust, although it's the language I'm currently focusing on.

I'm writing a function to parse a language (MySQL) into tokens and output them in a formatted way, and part of that includes looking up the current work token to see if it's a name, a function, or a column/table name.

Currently, I'm using a match statement like

```
pub fn is_word(word: &str) -> bool {
    match word {
        "accessible"
        | "account"
        | "action"
        | "active"
        | "add"
        // ...
        | "year"
        | "year_month"
        | "zerofill" => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

The [actual list](https://github.com/BrianLeishman/mysql-format/blob/master/src/words_match.rs) is much, much longer.

Is this the best way to go about this? I've tried using a `HashMap` as well with `.contains_key()`, but that was notably slower

---

My [`HashMap` implementation](https://github.com/BrianLeishman/mysql-format/blob/master/src/words_hashmap.rs) looks like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref words: HashMap<&'static str, u8> = hashmap!{
        "accessible" => 0,
        "account" => 0,
        "action" => 0,
        "active" => 0,
        "add" => 0,
        // ...
        "year" => 0,
        "year_month" => 0,
        "zerofill" => 0,
    };
}

pub fn is_word(word: &str) -> bool {
    words.contains_key(word)
}
```

Comment: How did you try with a hashmap?

Comment: I actually have that version next to the match.rs file https://github.com/BrianLeishman/mysql-format/blob/master/src/words_hashmap.rs

Comment: I've also added a snippet of that to the question :)

Comment: The default hashmap hasher is notoriously slow as it tries to protect against collision attacks. You might want to try with a faster implementation, for example https://docs.rs/fasthash/0.3.2/fasthash/

Comment: Yes, I figured that with the secure hashing it uses that it would likely be slow, I wrote it anyway as more of a learning exercise @DenysSéguret, but that definitely looks interesting I'll try that out as well

Comment: Why would you use a `HashMap` instead of a `HashSet`?

Comment: @Shepmaster not knowing what a `HashSet` is :)

Comment: maybe the [aho-corasick-algorithmn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) can work here. There is a [crate](https://github.com/BurntSushi/aho-corasick) for it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your list is fixed at compile time, use a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), such as that provided by the [phf crate](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-phf):

**build.rs**

```
extern crate phf_codegen;

use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new(&env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap()).join("codegen.rs");
    let mut file = BufWriter::new(File::create(&path).unwrap());

    write!(&mut file, "static KEYWORDS: phf::Set<&'static str> = ").unwrap();
    phf_codegen::Set::new()
        .entry("accessible")
        .entry("account")
        .entry("action")
        .entry("active")
        .entry("add")
        // ...
        .entry("year")
        .entry("year_month")
        .entry("zerofill")
        .build(&mut file)
        .unwrap();
    write!(&mut file, ";\n").unwrap();
}
```

**src/main.rs**

```
extern crate phf;

include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/codegen.rs"));

pub fn is_word(word: &str) -> bool {
    KEYWORDS.contains(word)
}
```

According to the benchmarking code you've provided, this is at least as fast.

Comment: Damn that's impressive, cut the time of the entire execution to a 3rd of what it was before this